# Object doesn't support property or method IE11 (Compatibility Mode) - knockoutjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

Essentially what I am trying to achieve here is to check if the Barcode inputted/scanned on the form which is stored in `self.trackfile` is already in the list of files.

`self.files()` is an array of arrays, each time the file is added it pushes another array from `self.trackfile` into `self.files()`, once all the files have been added into the list they can be 'tracked' and sent back to the server.

I am having trouble getting this to work in IE11 (Compatibility Mode), this works fine in Chrome. I have done some searching around and not found a workaround.

The line `var fb = self.files()[x].Barcode();` throws the following error in IE: `Object doesn't support property or method 'Barcode'`.

If you could help me identify a workaround that would be fantastic!

**addFile Script**

```
self.addFile = function () {
    var index = 0;

    if(index < self.files().length){
        var i = 0;

        for (x in self.files()){
            var fb = self.files()[x].Barcode();
            var tb = self.trackfile.Barcode();

            if(fb==tb){
                i += 1;
            }
        }
        if(i > 0){
            alert("Error: File Already Exists in List");
        }
        else {
            self.files.push(new TrackFile(self.trackfile));
        }
   }
   else {
       self.files.push(new TrackFile(self.trackfile));
   }
}
```

**Example of files()**

```
[
  {
    "Location": "Location 1",
    "TransactionMode": "Send",
    "ServicePoint": "Service Point 2",
    "Status": "Incomplete / Open",
    "Comments": "",
    "Barcode": "0123456789",
    "BarcodeImageBase64": ""
  },
  {
     "Location": "Location 1",
     "TransactionMode": "Send",
     "ServicePoint": "ServicePoint 1",
     "Status": "Incomplete / Open",
     "Comments": "",
     "Barcode": "9876543210",
     "BarcodeImageBase64": ""
  }
]
```

**console.log(self.files()[x]);**
[image]

Comment: Could you create a fiddle?

Comment: Yeah, i'll give it a go

Comment: sorry I am not managing to successfully recreate this in jsfiddle

Comment: Have you tried to debug the code and check the value of `self.files()[x]` at the time of the error?

Comment: added a screenshot of the output

Comment: The screenshot you've linked shouldn't throw an error. Are you sure it's not the line below that fails? (`self.trackfile.Barcode()`) Also, you might want to declare your `x` variable so that it doesn't get added to the global namespace. Other than that, without an example that reproduces the issue, it's hard to help.

Comment: I have figured out workaround that doesn't require my to return values from nested arrays, I will post my answer in case anyone else hits this problem. Thanks for your suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out how to get around this rather than trying to return a value from a nested array I created an array of just the barcodes:

```
self.justBarcodes = ko.computed(function() {
    var barcodes = ko.utils.arrayMap(this.files(), function(item) {
        return item.Barcode();
    });
    return barcodes.sort();
}, self);
```

Then I looped through the `self.justBarcodes()` array to check if the barcode already exists:

```
for (var x = 0; x < self.justBarcodes().length; x++){
    var fb = self.justBarcodes()[x];
    var tb = self.trackfile.Barcode();
    if(fb==tb){
        i += 1;
    }
}
```

Now it works as it should!

Comment: Well you still shouldn't use "for (x in self.justBarcodes())"

Answer (score 0):

Try looping through your array with indexes instead of the `for (x in foo)` construct. You're probably running into a random property on the prototype of the array that IE adds which obviously wouldn't contain a Barcode.

See: [Why is using "for...in" with array iteration a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-a-bad-idea)